# show image from sqlite database in uiimageview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, uiimageview

I have stored image path in sqlite and I successfully fetched image path from the database. I stored it in a string. I print the path in the console which is as follows:

```
2012-10-26 11:54:37.888 valvolineApp[1211:207] Image path:/Users/shufflelabs/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/6B6D67DB-92AB-48C5-856B-861423FB22F4/valvolineApp.app/11_fuel system service.jpg
```

but now how to show the respective image in the uiimageview?

I am very confusing here.

share the idea if you have

thanx...

Comment: where is the Image in Project or in the Database ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:(the file path)];
 UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
```

If u still facing problem similar posts are seen below.

[programmatically-show-image-in-uiimageview-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470354/cannot-programmatically-show-image-in-uiimageview-iphone)

[dispay-image-in-uiimageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674597/dispay-local-image-in-uiimageview)

[how-to-display-images-in-imageview-in-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518071/how-to-display-images-in-imageview-in-iphone)